# Troubles with margin-bottom and vh unit

Tags: html, css

I have a div who should scroll over the browser window. I have setted a top of 73vh and a margin-bottom of 100vh. So the effect should be, to scroll this div "out of the browser window". In Chrome this works like a charm, but in Firefox the margin-bottom is not the window-height.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  Hi!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 73vh;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
```

I have creaded a code-pen to reproduce: [Code Pen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEpVeW)

Open the CodePen in Chrome, the red box was moving out of the view, Open the CodePen in Firefox, the red box was moving just a little. I would like to have the effect of Chrome.

**SOLUTION**

Based on fcalderan answer: change top to margin-top, then it works with FF too. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PypXQw)

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 73vh;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: if you change top with margin-top it works as expected. it seems that firefox is computing the margin-bottom from the static position of the element (as if it was in position: static)

Comment: Yes, with margin-top instead of top it works! It seems that I should not mix top with margin. Thanks!

Comment: @fcalderan Just to clarify, when you say 'static position' you mean where the element would have been positioned if it hadn't been offset?

Comment: @Daniel exactly. As if the value was calculated without the top offset.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you make it border-bottom instead of margin bottom /shrug/:

```
.container {
 position: relative;
 top: 73vh;
 border-bottom: 100vh solid transparent;
 background: red;
 background-clip:padding-box; // credit to @fcalderan
}
```

linky https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/WapPvE

Not great, but a work around.

Comment: I'd suggest to use a transparent border, just to not cover any background eventually defined and `background-clip: padding-box;` (so the red background doesn't also fill the border area)

Comment: @fcalderan that picks up the red background of the div, even with box-sizing:content-box; over-flow:hidden on the .container

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten about background-clip! Excellent @fcalderan